# Haskell: Flaw in the description of applicative functor laws in the hackage Control.Applicative article?: it says Applicative determines Functor

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative, hackage

I think I found a flaw in [the hackage article for `Control.Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html).
As a description of the applicative functor laws, it says:

> ```
> class Functor f => Applicative f where
> ```
>
> A functor with application, providing operations to
>   embed pure expressions (`pure`), and sequence computations and combine their results (`<*>`).
>
> A minimal complete definition must include implementations of these functions satisfying the following laws:
>
> ***identity***
>
> ```
> pure id <*> v = v
> ```
>
> ***composition***
>
> ```
> pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w = u <*> (v <*> w)
> ```
>
> ***homomorphism***
>
> ```
> pure f <*> pure x = pure (f x)
> ```
>
> ***interchange***
>
> ```
> u <*> pure y = pure ($ y) <*> u
> ```

(note that this does not say anything about fmap) and it states that these laws determine the `Functor` instance:

> As a consequence of these laws, the `Functor` instance for f will satisfy
>
> ```
> fmap f x = pure f <*> x
> ```

I thought at first this was obviously wrong.  That is, I guessed there must exist a type constructor `t` satisfying the following two conditions:

1. `t` is an instance of `Applicative` fulfilling the rules above, and
2. There are two different implementations of `instance (Functor t)`
   (i.e. there are two distinct functions `fmap1, fmap2 :: (a->b) -> (t a->t b)`,
    satisfying the functor laws).

If (and only if) the above is correct, the above statement *must* be rewritten to

> The Functor instance for f must satisfy
>
> ```
> fmap f x = pure f <*> x
> ```
>
> As a consequence of these laws, this satisfies the `Functor` laws.

which is clearly correct, *no matter whether my guess is right or not*.

***My question is***: *is my guess correct? Is there a `t` with the desired conditions?*

---

What follows is the explanation of what I thought during trying to answer this question by myself.

If we were mere mathematicians *uninterested in actual Haskell programming*, we could easily answer this question affirmatively. In fact,

```
t = Identity
newtype Identity a = Identity {runIdentity :: a}
```

meets the requirements 1 and 2 above (in fact, almost anything will do). Indeed, `Identity` is trivially an instance of `Functor` and `Applicative`, as defined in [`Data.Functor.Identity`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html). (This satisfies `fmap f = (pure f <*>)`.)
To define another "implementation" of `instance (Functor f)`, Take, for each type `a`, two functions

```
transf_a, tinv_a :: a -> a
```

such that

```
tinv_a . transf_a = id
```

(This is, *set-theoretically*, easy). Now define

```
instance (Functor Identity) where
 fmap (f :: a->b) = Identity . transf_b . f . tinv_a . runIdentity
```

This satisfies the `Functor` laws and is a different implementation from the trivial one if there are

```
x :: a
f :: a -> b
```

such that

```
f x /= transf_b $ f $ tinv_a x
```

But it is not at all obvious whether we can do it in Haskell. Is something like:

```
class (Isom a) where
 transf, tinv :: a -> a

instance (Isom a) where
 transf = id
 tinv = id

specialized instance (Isom Bool) where
 transf = not
 tinv = not
```

possible in Haskell?

---

### Edit

I forgot to write something very important. I recognize `Control.Applicative` as part of GHC base package, so I am also interested in whether the answer to my question changes with any GHC language extensions, such as `FlexibleInstances` or `OverlappingInstances`, which I don't understand yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Any type in Haskell can have at most one instance of `Functor`, so your guess is not correct: For *no* type `t` (whether or not it's an instance of `Applicative`) can there exist two different implementations of `instance (Functor t)`. See: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.libraries/15384

Comment: A very nice consequence of the free theorem!

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer and reference! It seems that the free theorem is a good theorem, although I don't still understand it. Do you know whether the theorem holds under the GHC extensions (see my Edit in my questions)?

Comment: The only function of type `a -> a` is `id`, so `transf_a` and `tinv_a` are both `id` and `transf_a . tinv_a = id` is trivially true. (Up to bottoms, but [morally correct](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/fast+loose.pdf).)

Answer (score 2):

It is a property of the type `a -> a` that there are only two inhabitants of it, namely `id :: a -> a` (defined as `id x = x`) and `bottom :: a -> a` defined as `bottom = error "Infinite loop."`.

If we restrict ourselves to only the first case as "reasonable", we come to an important mathematical theorem, which is that there is at most one function `fmap` of type `forall a. forall b. (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` satisfying `fmap id = id` and `fmap f . fmap g = fmap (f . g)`.

If we do not, then you are correct, we have one case where `fmap = undefined` and the other where `fmap = (<*>) . pure`. But that's a little cheesy.

Comment: With `fmap = undefined`, `fmap id x = _|_` but `id x = x`, so it doesn't abide the functor laws.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Thanks for an important point that I missed. I was just taking gksato's proof for granted and thinking, "well, there's only two values of that type," but it didn't occur to me that one of the values violated the axioms.

Comment: Your point is correct, though: any type constructor has at most one *legal* definition of `fmap`. As chi mentions in another comment, this follows from the functor laws and the free theorem for `fmap`.